# Call C# delegate from CLI class that wraps native C++ class

Tags: c#, .net, native

I have a CLI wrapper to a C++ class. The C++ class has a callback that passes
a char* array, and the length of that array.

```
void (CPP_CALLBACK*)(char* data, unsigned int dataLength)
```

In C# land, I have this callback

```
  private delegate void AppPacketReceivedDelegate(byte[] data);
```

My CLI wrapper receives the CPP_CALLBACK callback, and must then somehow call the C# delegate.

Any ideas on how to do this ? I tried

```
System::Action<cli::array<char>^>
```

but I am not sure how to match the delegate to this Action.

Update:

I convert the delegate into a function pointer, and then I can call the function pointer from CLI using this syntax:

```
  typedef void(__stdcall * WRAPPER_APP_PACKET_CALLBACK) (cli::array<unsigned char>^);
```

But, when I call this, the array is always of size 1 !

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple example, not exactly matching your situation, but it could be quickly adapted.

**CppClass.h**

```
namespace MyCppNamespace
{
    typedef void (__stdcall *callback_function)(int, const char*);

    class CppClass
    {
    private:
        callback_function _callbackFunc;

    public:
        void DoSomething(callback_function callbackFunc);
    }
}
```

**DotNetClass.cs**

```
namespace MyManagedNamespace
{
    public delegate void ManagedCallback(int size, string message);
}
```

**CliWrapperClass.h**

```
#include "CppClass.h"

using namespace MyManagedNamespace;

namespace MyCliNamespace
{
    public ref class CliWrapperClass
    {
    private:
        CppClass *_cppClass;

    public:
        void DoSomething(ManagedCallback ^ callback);
    }
}
```

**CliWrapperClass.cpp**

```
#include "CliWrapperClass.h"

namespace MyCliNamespace
{
    void CliWrapperClass::DoSomething(ManagedCallback ^ callback)
    {        
        System::IntPtr callbackPtr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback);

        _cppClass->DoSomething(static_cast<callback_function>(callbackPtr.ToPointer())); 
    }
}
```

In the .Net class, you can create an instance of `CliWrapperClass` and call its `DoSomething(...)` function in this way:

```
namespace MyManagedNamespace
{
    public class ManagedClass
    {
        private ManagedCallback _callback = MyCallback;

        private void MyCallback(int size, string message)
        {
            // Do what you want ...
        }

        public void MyFunction()
        {
            CliWrapperClass wrapper = new CliWrapperClass();
            wrapper.DoSomething(_callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have the CLI wrapper set up. My issue is calling a callback from C++ and passing a C-style array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I marked the C# class and the corresponding delegate as `unsafe`, and
then I was able to call the delegate from C++ and pass over the C-style array. On the C# side, I created a managed array and copied the bytes over using `Marshal.Copy`